# Spring-AOP pointcut not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Below is my code snippet:

**ServiceImpl.java**

```java
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
  private Response worker(Audit send) throws ArgumentException {
    System.out.println("STEP_1");
    worker(send.getRequest(), send.getId());
  }

  private Response worker(Request request, String id) throws ArgumentException {
    System.out.println("STEP_2");
    try {
      //throwing some exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("STEP_3");
    }
  }
}
```

Now, what I want is whenever `NullPointerException` is being thrown from method `worker(Request request, String id)` as shown above I want to perform some specific task. For that I have written an Aspect class which is following:

**MyAspect.java**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect{
  @Pointcut("com.xyz.myapp.ServiceImpl.worker() && args(request,..)")
  private void someOperation(Request request) {}

  @Before("someOperation(request)")
  public void process(Request request) {
    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
  }

  @AfterThrowing("com.xyz.myapp.ServiceImpl.worker() && args(request,..)")
  public void doRecoveryActions() {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION_SUCCESS");
  }
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
STEP_1 
STEP_2
STEP_3
```

**Desired Output:**

```
STEP_1 
STEP_2
STEP_3
SUCCESS
EXCEPTION_SUCCESS
```

As you can see `MyAspect.java` is not getting triggered hence NOT printing values.
What can be the reason for this?

**Note:**

1. I tried making worker as public classes too but it didn't work.
2. Also tried changing the name of the methods to eliminate any overloading issue that too didn't work.
3. Tried various other pointcut expressions all in vain as of now.
4. In my application there are other aspect classes working absolutely fine.

Comment: Did you ensure that MyAspect was added to your application context?

Comment: I don't think I made any entry for that. Also I don't know what/where exactly is application context. I'm working on an existing system.

Comment: I would start with ensuring sprint is aware of MyAspect (ie it has been added to the application context).  This is generally done via `application-context.xml` or via class path scanning.  You already have @Component on the class, which is good, but you just need to make sure spring is aware of the class.

Comment: I could not find application-context.xml in my application. So as a workaround I put my code in an existing Aspect. There also getting same error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error I mean I am not able to see my  log.debug("I am in doAfterThrowingException"); in the logs. Is there any other way to find out if my Aspect is triggered? I am not aware of any other way.

Comment: 2 questions. Is there a typo in the package or class b or method name?  Do you your logger set to print out debug messages? As a quick check,  I would change debug to error or fatal; which ever is the highest for your logging library.

Comment: Before you bother about narrowing down the scope of your aspect, first it should run at all. I think it makes sense to read the fine Spring manual, especially the chapter about [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), and the come back here if afterwards you still have questions. Working on an existing application as a newbie is no excuse not to learn about the technologies used there befor you mess up the code. I mean no offense, but StackOverflow is hardly the right platform for you to delegate your work to others.

Comment: Another recommendation to you if you want to get good answers here: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so as to enable other users to reproduce and understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @kriegaex. I have tried making some changes to the question. hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a typical Spring AOP beginner's mistake: You assume that it works for private methods, but as the documentation clearly says, it does not. Spring AOP is based on dynamic proxies, and those only work for public methods when implementing interfaces via JDK proxies and additionally for protected and package-scoped methods when using CGLIB proxies.

You should make the `worker()` method public if you want to intercept it from an aspect.

P.S.: Full-fledged AspectJ also works for private methods, but to switch to another AOP framework would be overkill here.

---

**Update:** You also have other problems in your code:

- The first `worker` method, even if you make it public, does not return anything. The last statement should be `return worker(send.getRequest(), send.getId());`, not just `worker(send.getRequest(), send.getId());`.
- Your pointcut `com.xyz.myapp.ServiceImpl.worker()` will never match because it has an empty argument list, but your method has arguments. The `args()` does not help you here.
- The syntax of your pointcut is also wrong because it does not specify a return type for the method, not even `*`. Furthermore, the method name itself is not enough, it should be enclosed in an actual pointcut type such as `execution()`. I.e. you want to write something like:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.myapp.ServiceImpl.worker(..)) && args(request, ..)")
private void someOperation(Request request) {}
```

Comment: I tried making them public also but that too didn't work for me.

Comment: Does AOP work in other cases in the very same project? We need to find out if there is a configuration problem or just a problem in your aspect.

Comment: Yup, its working in the same project. I checked the other classes as well and found out that those are standalone classes i.e. they are not extending/implementing any other classes/interfaces. But in my case the class implements an interface "Service.java". One more thing that the method worker() is specific to my class only, its not an overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

To intercept a method that throws an exception you can use this code (works only if methods are public):

```
 @AfterThrowing(pointcut="com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()",throwing="ex")
         public void doRecoveryActions(NullPointerException ex) {
          // ...
         }
```

Source: [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)